# Minimax Connect 4 AI trouble

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am making connect 4 AI, except the game continues until all 42 spaces are filled.
Score is kept by every 4 in a row gets 1 point.

```
public int[] Max_Value(GameBoard playBoard, int depth){
    GameBoard temp = new GameBoard(playBoard.playBoard);
    int h = 0, tempH = 999, tempCol=0;
    int myDepth = depth - 1;
    int[] tempH2 = new int[2];
    boolean noChildren = true;
    if(myDepth != -1){
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            if(temp.isValidPlay(i)){
                count++;
                temp.playPiece(i);
                noChildren = false;
                tempH2 = Min_Value(temp, myDepth);
                if(tempH2[1] < tempH){
                    tempH=tempH2[1];
                    tempCol = i;
                }
                temp.removePiece(i);
            }
        }
    }   
    int[] x = new int[2];
    if(noChildren){
        h = temp.getHeuristic();
    }
    else{
        h = tempH;
        x[0]=tempCol;
    }
    x[1]=h;
    return x; 
}

public int[] Min_Value(GameBoard playBoard, int depth){
    GameBoard temp = new GameBoard(playBoard.playBoard);
    int h = 0, tempH = -999, tempCol=0;
    int myDepth = depth - 1;
    int[] tempH2 = new int[2];
    boolean noChildren = true;
    if(myDepth != -1){
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            if(temp.isValidPlay(i)){
                count++;
                temp.playPiece(i);
                noChildren = false;
                tempH2 = Max_Value(temp, myDepth);
                if(tempH2[1] > tempH){
                    tempH=tempH2[1];
                    tempCol = i;
                }
                temp.removePiece(i);
            }
        }
    }   
    int[] x = new int[2];
    if(noChildren){
        h = temp.getHeuristic();
    }
    else{
        h = tempH;
        x[0]=tempCol;
    }
    x[1]=h;
    return x; 
}
```

I feel like I just stumbled through everything, and it feels like terrible code.  However, I have never attempted anything like this before, and would appreciate any input.  I can't tell where I am going wrong. My evaluation function just gives 1 point for each 4 in a row it can find for any given state. The main function calls the Min_Value function to start things off with a depth of 10.

I am attempting to return the column as well as the value of the heuristic. I hope I have provided enough information.  Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, after implementing the methods not shown (like evaluation, playmove, remove etc.) I was able to debug this. Assuming that these functions are implemented in some correct way in your version, the mistake is that you never actually call the evaluation function if depth is -1:

You have this:

```
[...]if(myDepth != -1)
{/*restofthecode*/}[...]
```

But what you need is something like this:

```
[...]if(myDepth == -1)
{
return temp.getHeuristic();
}
/*restofthecode*/
[...]
```

That way, whenever you reach depth -1 (a leaf in your minimax tree), the board will be evaluated and the value returned (which is excactly what you need in minimax).

Do this modification in both parts (min and max) and everything shuold be allright. If there are other problems, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it isn't stated in the question, I think you are not getting good moves from your search, right?

Without looking through your while code, I can already say that your program will only work during the last 10 moves of the game (last 10 empty fields or forced win in 10). Otherwise, your program will return either the last or the first move it evaluated. That is because of your evaluation function, where you only handle a win (respectively 4 in a row), but not 2 in a row, traps, 3 in a row, etc.). It will think of all moves as equal if it can't force a win.

This is a problem, because starting with an empty field, a win can only be forced by the starting player, and just with the 2nd last piece to be placed on the board. (In your version 4 in a row forced).

And since your searchdepth (10) is smaller than the maximum game moves (42), your program will always play its first move.

If the rest of your algorithm is correctly implemented, you can fix this by simply improve your evaluation function, so that it can differ between "good" and "bad" game positions.

Comment: Thank you. I was just starting with the bad evaluation function to make sure that at least worked as it is easier to check. I was only checking it on a board in which the top row is empty (only 7 moves left). However, it still wouldn't make a move that gave a connect 4, even though one was available. Also, when I tried to run it on an empty board, the program would stall out, even at depth 5, which I don't think it should. I would think the time would be 7^5 on an empty board at depth 5. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2587878 Well, the cool thing is that I can copy paste this into visual studio and debug it with the excellent debugger. I'll try to solve this later today and post another answer in here if I can find the bug(s).

Comment: Edit: be aware that your methodnames are inversed, your Min method calculates the maximising players value => could cause confusion